# Delegation of Member function

Tags: c++, function, class, initialization, member

I searched a lot for something like delegation of member functions but I did not find something about it. Maybe I searched for the wrong words...

I try to do something like the following:

```
    class Foo1 {
        int bar(int a, int b = 1, bool c = false);
        int bar(int a, bool c);
    }

    // Can I write it like:
    class Foo2 {
        int bar(int a, int b = 1, bool c = false);
        // This line is my question:
        int bar(int a, bool c) : bar(a, 1, c);
    }
```

My compiler said that only constructors take init lists but I think I read something like the above somewhere. Are there any exceptions from the rule that only constructors take init lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An init-list is for initializing the bases and members of a class object, which only makes sense for a class constructor.  A function has nothing to initialize (except for the function parameters, which are automatically initialized from the arguments passed at each call).

But to defer one function to another is easy: you just call the other function in the first function's body.

```
class Foo2 {
    int bar(int a, int b = 1, bool c = false);
    int bar(int a, bool c) { return bar(a, 1, c); }
};
```

Comment: I thought it could be reduce performance if I have to "delegate" over 10 functions and more. I thought that it could be faster if I tell the compiler that it should call the real bar function instead of going inside the functions body and call the real one then. Did I thought wrong?

Comment: @HenrikViebrock Assuming you enable optimizations, compilers will often "inline" small functions, eliminating the function call overhead.  Also, constructor mem-initializers are often actually function calls anyway.

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear, you can't do that kind of delegation in member function.

What you can do is simply call some other member function in some member funcion, passing an arguments, like:

```
class Foo1 {
    int bar(int a, int b = 1, bool c = false);
    int bar(int a, bool c);
}

// Can I write it like:
class Foo2 {
    int bar(int a, int b = 1, bool c = false);

    // Should be inlined by default, but won't hurt to specify it explicitly
    inline int bar(int a, bool c) {
        return bar(a, 1, c);
    }
}
```

The call to bar with two parameters shouldn't have any performance drawbacks.

Comment: Don't I have to write a *return* inside the inline function?